# Python EOF identify if a line is after

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new in python, this is my code

```
for myPath,item in dicts.items():
   for elem in item:
     thefile = open(elem, 'r')
     for line1,line2 in itertools.izip_longest(*[thefile]*2):
        if ('namespace' in line1) or ('namespace' in line2):
           return True
        if line2 is None:  (this condition dont work)
           continue
```

I need to identify if line2 is after EOF to take another element in item

now my condition dont work. 
Thanks

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Does it give you an error or simply does not do what you want? If so, what *does* it do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to avoid the `TypeError` from `'namespace' in None`, then do it another way instead and have `line2` be an empty string. Note that `iter` has been added as I assume you're trying to group the file into pairs... (but then not sure what this gains over just line by line...)

```
for line1,line2 in itertools.izip_longest(*[iter(thefile)]*2, fillvalue='')
```

Note:

Your entire criteria looks like it could be (thanks to kindall for spotting mistake):

```
return any('namespace' in line for line in thefile)
```

Comment: @user2623211 looks like your entire criteria just needs to be `return any('namespace' in thefile)` for what you show that you're doing...

Comment: I just add fillvalue = '' like clement and it work now, when i have an extra line, it is automatically replace by None and my code continue.

Comment: `any('namespace' in theFile)` is not going to do at all what you want. `'namespace' in theFile` is going to return `True` only if there is a line in the file whose contents are exactly `'namespace'` (which, because lines include newlines, can only be true at the end of the file and only if it doesn't end with a newline). And `any()` is going to barf because it has been given a single Boolean value, but it wants an iterable.

Comment: @kindall I meant `any('namespace' in line for line in thefile)` of course... but good spot ;)